# CustomScrollView with CupertinoTabView causing list enties to be covered

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm very new to flutter and have a confusing problem with `CustomScrollView`. The first entry in the list is always covered by the `CupertinoNavigationBar` and the last item is covered by the `CupertinoTabView` controls. If I switch out the `CustomScrollView` with a simple `ListView` the scrollable area renders as expected. The code below shows this behavior. To see the working version, uncomment the `ListView` and comment the `CustomScrollView`. You can run the example here: https://dartpad.dev/92320bae18a4f12ed99abe38cf643dea?null_safety=true

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoApp(
      theme: const CupertinoThemeData(brightness: Brightness.light),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.check_mark),
            label: 'TODO List',
          ),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.gear),
            label: 'Settings',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        late final CupertinoTabView returnValue;
        switch (index) {
          case 0:
            returnValue = CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
              return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(middle: Text('TODOs')),
                
//                 // Using ListView scrolling works as expected
//                 child: ListView(
//                   children: 
//                     List.generate(
//                       30,
//                       (index) => Container(
//                         height: 50,
//                         color: Colors.amber[100 * (index % 6 + 1)],
//                         child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index + 1}')),
//                       ),
//                     )
//                 ),
                
                // Using CustomScrollView we can't scroll to entries 1 or 30
                child: CustomScrollView(
                  slivers: <Widget>[
                    SliverList(
                      delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                        List.generate(
                          30,
                          (index) => Container(
                            height: 50,
                            color: Colors.amber[100 * (index % 6 + 1)],
                            child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index + 1}')),
                          ),
                        )
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]
                ),
                
              );
            });
            break;

            case 1:
              returnValue = CupertinoTabView(builder: (context) {
                return CupertinoPageScaffold(
                  navigationBar: CupertinoNavigationBar(
                    middle: Text('Settings'),
                  ),

                  child: CustomScrollView(),
                );
              });
              break;
        }
        
        return returnValue;
      },
    );
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the `CupertinoNavigationBar` overlaping the `CustomScrollView` you need to make the `CustomScrollView` in a `SafeArea`

```
            child: SafeArea( 
              child: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                    List.generate(
                      30,
                      (index) => Container(
                        height: 50,
                        color: Colors.amber[100 * (index % 6 + 1)],
                        child: Center(child: Text('Entry ${index + 1}')),
                      ),
                    )
                  ),
                ),
              ]
             ),
            )
```